# Slick carousel content does not show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with a slick carousel that loads and works (verified with Element Inspector) but does not appears on screen. Another slick carousel works fine in the same page. I've gone through it many times but can't find the problem and it's driving me nuts. Here's the link to the page, go to EXPERIENCIA section:

http://nhtest.esy.es/buro/index-06-06.html

Notice that the containing div displays perfectly, I've added it some text and a red border to check it.

You can see below the navbar that the main slick carousel works fine, but this other one doesn't display its contents. If you inspect it in small devices size, you can see that the first image loads, and then disappears, and if you look in the code inspector, you will see it working, but not displaying. For some reason it doesn't even show the first image in responsive inspection mode.

Looking forward to your answers, many thanks in advance!

Comment: fix your code errors then try https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I´ve fixed a lot of code errors but that didn´t solve the issue. However, I´ve found that changing overflow property in slick.css from "hidden" to "visible" displays the images, but now I have another problem: it expands the page width to the slick width.